# Find the numbers in the following sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$\left\{ X: X \in \{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\}\} \wedge x \not\subseteq \{2,3,4\} \right\} = A$

Well, I did some work on it and I've found that $ A=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\} $.

which means $|A| = 2$

Is that true? also, if possible, I'd like to see how you solve it.

(I know I could write it better, just was lazy)
[image])

Comment: Your definition of $A$ contradicted your pic and your conclusion: from your pic and your work, you want & mean the $X$ that are **not** contained in $\{2,3,4\}$, yes? I edited your question to reflect this.

Comment: @BrianO Refrain the picture, it is just something I did for myself to find those 2 elements. and I defined A as D on my picture.

Comment: I noticed $A$ was $D$ in the pic, didn't bother me :) But you do mean "is **not** a subset of", right? In any case, yes you got the correct answer.